# Using Freelancer TNG 2.7.6, I found nexus WH, but it says access denied?

Tags: mods, freelancer

I'm playing freelancer and looked through many forums to find where the door to nexus is, and when I get there, it says access denied. Why did it lock me out? Do I have to finish the story line or something, or is it a bug, or is there a file I have to alter in something to grant me access to the nexus?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help you with your question but I had no idea this mod exists!  I am so installing this as soon as I get home from work.